# How to proceed a reaction between piperidine and cyclopropyl methyl carbocation!

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Since cyclopropyl methyl cation is highly stable, I proceeded through SN1 as elimination is not possible because of strain in the ring. Need help now in approaching the question.

Actually the given answer is 2, but I am getting no π bonds.

Comment: The cation created by SN1 is highly hindered for approach by the piperidine. Consider the possibility of nucleophilic attack at one of the methylenes of the [3] ring followed by ring opening.